# Iterate over images with pattern

Tags: python-3.x, iteration

I have thousands of images which are labeled `IMG_####_0` where the first image is `IMG_0001_0.png` the 22nd is `IMG_0022_0.png`, the 100th is `IMG_0100_0.png` etc. I want to perform some tasks by iterating over them. 
I used this `fnames = ['IMG_{}_0.png'.format(i) for i in range(150)]` to iterate over the first `150` images but I get this error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/me/images/IMG_0_0.png'` which suggests that it is not the correct way to do it. Any ideas about how to capture this pattern while being able to iterate over the specified number of images i.e in my case from `IMG_0001_0.png` to `IMG_0150_0.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fnames = ['IMG_{0:04d}_0.png'.format(i) for i in range(1,151)]
print(fnames)

for fn in fnames:
    try:
        with open(fn, "r") as reader:
            # do smth here            
            pass
    except ( FileNotFoundError,OSError) as err:
        print(err)
```

Output:

```
  ['IMG_0000_0.png', 'IMG_0001_0.png', ...,  'IMG_0148_0.png', 'IMG_0149_0.png']
```

Dokumentation: [string-format()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format)
and [format mini specification](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec).

```
'{:04d}' # format the given parameter with 0 filled to 4 digits as decimal integer
```

The other way to do it would be to create a normal string and fill it with 0:

```
print(str(22).zfill(10))
```

Output:

```
0000000022
```

But for your case, format language makes more sense.

Comment: The trick is my images begin from `IMG_0001_0.png`   so if I apply your code I will still get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/me/images/IMG_0000_0.png`. Any way around this?

Comment: @WasswaSamuel  1st: use `range(1,80)` to generate 1-79. 2nd: use error handling. Modified code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [format pattern](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#formatspec) to get the format you're looking for. You don't just want the integer converted to a string, you specifically want it to always be a string with four digits, using leading 0's to fill in any empty space. The best way to do this is:

```
'IMG_{:04d}_0.png'.format(i)
```

instead of your current format string. The result looks like this:

```
In [2]: 'IMG_{:04d}_0.png'.format(3)
Out[2]: 'IMG_0003_0.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

generate list of possible names and try if exist is slow and horrible way to iterate over files.

try look to [https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html](http://Python%20Glob%20module)

so something like:

```
from glob import iglob

filenames = iglob("/path/to/folder/IMG_*_0.png")
```